# How to convert the target framework from .net 5.0 to .net standard?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard, .net-5

I was making a nuget package, using basic libs in .net(no libs which can only be accessed in .net core). when I was trying the change the target framework in .csproj file from .net 5.0 to .net standard. `dotnet run` command seems not work, and the error message is as follows:

```
Unable to run project.
Please make sure you have a runnable project type and "dotnet run" supports this project.
A runnable project should be oriented to a runnable TFM (for example, net5.0) with an output type of "exe".
The current outputtype is "exe".
```

As the error message is in Chinese, I just roughly translate it to English. It might not be very  accurate. I want to find the right way to convert the TFM

Comment: .NET Standard is an API standard, not a framework, and executables cannot target it, only libraries can.

Comment: I want to make a NuGet package, how could I set the framwork to .NET standard? Change this when I publish?

Comment: If you're creating a package there's no need for `dotnet run`. `dotnet pack` produces a package.

Comment: So I could just change the TFM to `netstandard2.1` and dotnet pack and then I can solve the problem?